# How to replace notification sounds in Simplescreenrecorder

Tags: sound

I have been recording with [simplescreenrecorder](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) for a long time and rarely had any issues, but every once in a while, h264_nvenc spits out an error and stops recording. It’s not a huge deal, I just click record again and continue where I left off, but it *is* a problem when I don’t hear the notification sound. Problem is, the notification sound is quite gentle. I want to replace it with something that beeps real hard, blasts my ears off.

But I cannot find the files to replace. I looked into ~/.ssr, /usr/share/simplescreenrecorder and hit a search, but no relevant results. I then turned to the internet, but couldn’t find anything related to my question.

I’m using Ubuntu-Unity 22.04 and have installed ssr with "apt install simplescreenrecorder".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You can ask [here](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/troubleshooting/)